# An inner product on the dual space of a non-complete inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

As is well known, for any Hilbert space $V$, there is a natural inner product on the continuous dual. (the space of all continuous linear functionals).

Is there a way to endow an inner product on the algebraic dual of an infinite dimensional inner product space? (which should be connected somehow to the inner product of the original space)

what about the continuous dual (of non-complete spaces)?

Comment: One naive inner product you could put on the continuous dual might be something akin to $$\langle f,g\rangle = \sum_{x\in B}f(x)\overline{g(x)}$$ where $B$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$. There are two major issues with this: showing that it is well-defined (basis independent) and finiteness. I've dealt with things like this, but in slightly different situations where I was constructing a Hilbert space in such a way so I was able to force finiteness *a priori.*

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be done with the algebraic dual since you would have issues with continuity and inner products but I might be wrong.

Comment: I have only studied a very rudimentary amount of analysis so this does not constitute a hint or an answer. Based on past readings on (very) basic harmonic analysis, given a separable pre-Hilbert Space, isn't this what the Hilbert-Schmidt operator is intended to address?

Comment: The continuous dual of a space is the same as the continuous dual of its completion. The continuous linear functionals on the space extend uniquely to the completion of the space.